# TextInput placeHolder Alignment

Tags: react-native

What is the best way to align the placeholder text for TextInput component? I have already attempted to use the styles component as described below. There doesn't seem to be a property for this.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
             <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
                    username: text
                })}
                placeholder='Add Username'
             />
      </View>
    );
}

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
 },
 textInput: {
    height: 40,
    width: 200,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
 }

});
```

Comment: Text is not aligned to center in my case i'm using material-kit. what may be the problem? or is it working fine

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add `textAlign: 'center'` to your textInput style.

Comment: Text is not aligned to center in my case i'm using material-kit. what may be the problem? or is it working fine

Answer (score 9):

Add `textAlign={'center'}` as a property to the TextInput component

Answer (score 3):

if you doesnt give multiline property of textinput 'true'

place holder is always center of text input

you can give padding for example paddingTop

to  style of textInput

to make distance between place holder and textinput

Comment: This does not seem right

Answer (score 1):

set TextInput style padding:0 and adjust spacing accordingly