# How to place placeholder to center in react-native

Tags: react-native

*My code is :*

```
 <TextInput
            
              multiline={true}
              value={inputValue}
          
            />
```

*Placeholder is on middle on android, however on ios it is on top.*

> textAlignVertical

*is not work on ios*

i used text `alignItems: 'center'` and `alignSelf: center` these are not work as well.

*How can i handle this ?*

Comment: might be a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358153/textinput-placeholder-alignment

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the prop textAlignVertical for the TextInput component. Set this prop to "top" and the problem is solved.

```
<TextInput
   multiline={true}
   value={inputValue}
   textAlignVertical='top'
/>
```

Comment: @hakan That's strange. Actually, this is how it should work. Can you post more code from your TextInput component including the styles?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalignvertical   it is for only android

Comment: I don't mean the styleprops for the Text. The component textAlignVertical "top" aligns the text to the top on iOS and Android when you use multilin.

Comment: yes i tried that however didnt effect anything on ios :/

Comment: textAlignVertical is an android only prop

Answer (score 0):

Just Add textAlign: 'center' to your textInput style.

Comment: it is for horizontal.  I want to center vertical